# Array empty after array_push

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, mysqli

The array `$response` is empty after the array_push command  and I don't know why. I tested if the array `$product` is populated and it was.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response = array();
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

    $product = array();
    $product[name] = $result['name'];
    $product[inn] = $result['inn'];
    $product[analgetikagroup] = $result['analgetikagroup'];
    $product[wholevel] = $result['wholevel'];
    $product[dailydose] = $result['dailydose'];
    $product[contraindication] = $result['contraindication'];
    $product[sideeffect] = $result['sideeffect'];
    $product[gastricprotection] = $result['gastricprotection'];
    $response[success] = 1;
    $response[product] = array();
    array_push($response[product],$product);

    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: At the top of your script put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and then while you're fixing everything else that's wrong with your code you'll find the specific error that's causing you problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's not empty - maybe you are not going inside the "if". If I remove the "if" it works

```
php >
php >     $product = array();
php >     $product[name] = $result['name'];
php >     $product[inn] = $result['inn'];
php >     $product[analgetikagroup] = $result['analgetikagroup'];
php >     $product[wholevel] = $result['wholevel'];
php >     $product[dailydose] = $result['dailydose'];
php >     $product[contraindication] = $result['contraindication'];
php >     $product[sideeffect] = $result['sideeffect'];
php >     $product[gastricprotection] = $result['gastricprotection'];
php >     $response[success] = 1;
php >     $response[product] = array();
php >     array_push($response[product],$product);
php >
php >
php >
php > echo json_encode($response);
{"success":1,"product":[{"name":null,"inn":null,"analgetikagroup":null,"wholevel":null,"dailydose":null,"contraindication":null,"sideeffect":null,"gastricprotection":null}]}
php >
```

Comment: Nope this doesn't work either. In your example the variables are `null`. If I don't populate the array with the data from the DB it works and I get a legit json response, but if the array is populated I get nothing.

Comment: I found a solution in another article but thanks for your try to help me to fix this problem :) PS: I would give you an upvote but my reputation is to low to upvote answers